# SSAS Currency Format measures displaying an * instead of a $ on upgrade from Cognos 8.2 to 8.4

Tags: ssas, cognos

Reports against an SSAS 2005 cube with Currency formatted measures.  In Cognos 8.2 a $ is properly displayed.  In Cognos 8.4 an * is displayed instead of a $. Have you encountered this problem, and how have you worked around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally just changed the formatting in SSAS to number with 2 decimals rather than currency, and the report builder added $ signs in the reports.